# How to define a make target ONLY in the same directory as the Makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I need a makefile with a wildcard rule that is only used for targets in the root of my codebase.

Let's say I have the following rules in my Makefile:

```
%.md:
    @echo "Running rule '%.md' for target '$@'."

md/%:
    @echo "Running rule 'md/%' for target '$@'."
```

When I run `make ex1.md md/ex2.md unknown/ex3.md`, I get this result:

```
Running rule '%.md' for target 'ex1.md'.
Running rule '%.md' for target 'md/ex2.md'.
Running rule '%.md' for target 'unknown/ex3.md'.
```

The expected result is:

```
Running rule '%.md' for target 'ex1.md'.
Running rule 'md/%' for target 'md/ex2.md'.
make: *** No rule to make target 'unknown/ex3.md'.  Stop.
```

To clarify, `%.md` should only run for `md` files in the same directory as the `Makefile`, and nowhere else.

For completeness, I am aware that the order of the rules in the Makefile matter, and flipping the order of the two rules above would "work" for `md/ex2.md`. This is not enough to solve the problem, as I also want `make unknown/ex3.md` to fail rather than running `%.md`.

Is there a way to do that with GNU Make?

The closest documentation pages I found about it are these:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Match.html
- https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Search-Algorithm.html

---

Updates:

- All the recipes in question are "PHONY". They are not really meant to create files, as `make` was designed to do.
- None of the recipes have real prerequisites, but introducing some fake ones as a workaround would be acceptable.
- The best solution so far was to (1) reorder rules, and (2) check the `$(@D)` (automatic variable)[https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables], like this:

```
md/%:
    @echo "Running rule 'md/%' for target '$@'."

%.md:
    @if [ "$(@D)" != '.' ]; then echo "Rule '%.md' is only meant for files on the current dir."; exit 1; fi
    @echo "Running rule '%.md' for target '$@'."
```

The result is this:

```
$ make ex1.md md/ex2.md unknown/ex3.md
Running rule '%.md' for target 'ex1.md'.
Running rule 'md/%' for target 'md/ex2.md'.
Rule '%.md' is only meant for files on the current dir.
make: *** [Makefile:127: unknown/ex3.md] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If recursive make is acceptable you could try:

```
$ cat Makefile
%.md:
ifeq ($(MODE),)
    $(MAKE) MODE=$(@D) $@
else ifeq ($(MODE),.)
    echo "Running rule '%.md' for target '$@'."
endif

md/%:
    echo "Running rule 'md/%' for target '$@'."

$ make -s ex1.md md/ex2.md unknown/ex3.md
Running rule '%.md' for target 'ex1.md'.
Running rule 'md/%' for target 'md/ex2.md'.
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'unknown/ex3.md'.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:3: unknown/ex3.md] Error 2
```

The idea is to use conditionals to separate the recipes for `%.md` files:

1. No mode defined: the recipe for `%.md` calls make again with the mode set to the directory part (`.` or other).
2. `.` mode: the recipe for `%.md` is that for files in the root directory.
3. Other mode: no recipe for `%.md`. If another rule applies (e.g. `md/%` for `md/ex2.md`), it is chosen, else make stops with an error (`unknown/ex3.md`).

Note that the top make will fail and stop on the first encountered error, so:

```
make -s unknown/ex3.md ex1.md md/ex2.md
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'unknown/ex3.md'.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:3: unknown/ex3.md] Error 2
```

If you prefer to continue building the other valid targets (and if you are OK with a 0 exit status) just add `-` on front of the recipe:

```
    -$(MAKE) MODE=$(@D) $@
```

Comment: This would effectively break the `md/%` rule for for a non `.md` files, like `md/ex69.notmd`. I'd like to leave that rule untouched, if possible.

Comment: You Makefile only has a rule for `%.md`, which wouldn't match a `.notmd` file. You merged the `md/%` into the one that is special. But I think I know a tweak that would solve it. We can remove the `ifeq ($(MODE),md)`. With a small edit, this looks like the best answer to me.

Comment: I do want a separate `md/%` rule. But then both would match `md/ex2.md`, which forces you to have that `ifeq ($(MODE),md)`. This is an issue. Now, about the `-`, I don't think it should be there. It causes `make unknown/ex3.md` to exit with 0, which is not desirable. If you don't object, I can edit the answer to what would work.

Comment: I tink I got your various points and edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: thank you! That solves it. I'm surprised that you don't need to put the `%.md:` line inside the `ifeq` block. When `$(MODE)`, that recipe still exists, but is empty. I didn't know `make` would doesn't match against those.

Comment: Yeah, the algorithm `make` runs to select rules is rather complicated. If you are interested you can find it [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rule-Search). Point number 4: _Remove from the list all rules with no recipe_.

Answer (score 0):

A GNU Make stem (`%`) will always match pathnames.  There's no facility in GNU Make to only match filenames without the directory, so it's not possible to require the stem `%` in `%.md` to only match files but not paths.  So the final requirement you have (that `unknown/ex3.md` give an error) is not possible, on its own.

However, a pattern will only match *IF* its prerequisites exist.  So, one option would be to list the directory as a prerequisite of these patterns.  That way if someone uses a non-existent directory, the pattern will not match.

Unfortunately listing directories as prerequisites is tricky because their timestamps have somewhat different behavior than files.  There are a few ways to think about this but really before we can suggest one we would need to know more about your needs.  For example is it REALLY the case that your pattern rules have no prerequisites?  So that you only want them to run when the target doesn't exist?  Or are they more complex?

Comment: Wouldn't `$(wildcard .)/*.md: $(wildcard .)/%.md : %.prereq` be a viable, if unorthodox, possibility?

Comment: I don't understand what that would to.  `$(wildcard .)` _always_ evaluates to `.` so this is identica to writing `./*.md: ./%.md : %.prereq`.  And I don't know where the `%.prereq` comes from?  Of course you can use static pattern rules if that's appropriate but that's not always the case, that's why i suggested we can't really help without knowing more details.

Comment: I was thinking about `abspath`, sorry my bad. `prereq` was just my guess as the OP didn't give any prerequisites. `abspath` is of course also not necessary ofc. But in principle, this static pattern rule restricts the targets to the makefile directory, no?

Comment: There are no real prerequisites for any of those rules. The targets are actually all PHONY. I'm open to introducing a fake prereq if that would allow solving the problem. The best workaround I found so far is to use `if [ "$(@D)" != '.' ]`, which looks at any directory path mentioned in the target.

Comment: If there are no prerequisites and they're all PHONY, then how do you choose which targets to build?  Is there some variable that contains the targets to be built?  Or do you rely on the user to provide some target(s) on the make command line?  I don't think using a shell if-statement is a good solution.  We can definitely do better than that.